# How to set a class name dependant on another attribute of the same element in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I want to set a conditional class based on an attribute of the same element so that I can stay dry. At first I got this:

```html
  <div class="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-3">
    <a href="#Index" class="navBarLink {currentPageName == 'Index' ? 'activeLink' : ''}">Farm</a>
    <a href="#/Leaderboard" class="navBarLink {currentPageName == 'Leaderboard' ? 'activeLink' : ''}">LeaderBoard</a>
    <a href="#/WafBox" class="navBarLink {currentPageName == 'WafBox' ? 'activeLink' : ''}">WafBox</a>
    <a href="#/Buy" class="navBarLink {currentPageName == 'Buy' ? 'activeLink' : ''}">Buy</a>
    <a href="#/Info" class="navBarLink {currentPageName == 'Info' ? 'activeLink' : ''}">Info</a>
</div>
```

Now I would like this:

```html
  <div class="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-3">
    <a href="#Index" class="navBarLink {isActive(this)}">Farm</a>
    <a href="#/Leaderboard" class="navBarLink {isActive(this)}">LeaderBoard</a>
    <a href="#/WafBox" class="navBarLink {isActive(this)}">WafBox</a>
    <a href="#/Buy" class="navBarLink {isActive(this)}">Buy</a>
    <a href="#/Info" class="navBarLink {isActive(this)}">Info</a>
  </div>
```

Then I would simply have to check the attribute of `href` in my function `isActive`. But here `this` does not seem to have the right informations inside. Is there a way to do it ? It would clean my code a lot

Edit: `isActive()` would look like this:

```html
<script>
  function isActive(element) {
    return 'Active' if (currentPageName == element.attr('href'))
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How does the `isActive()` function look like? Is it only checking `currentPageName == 'Leaderboard'`?

Comment: indeed it would look like this `  function isActive(element) {
    return 'Active' if (currentPageName == element.attr('href'))
  }`
Just updated my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your approach is that both in

```html
<a href="#/Leaderboard" class="navBarLink {isActive(this)}">LeaderBoard</a>
```

and the proposed answer using the class:directive

```html
 <a href="#Index" class:active-link={isActive('Index')}>Index</a>
```

is that the function will only run **once**, at the first render and then never re-execute, not even when `currentPageName` changes.

The most obvious, straight solution would be to simply ditch the function call and use the class:directive like this:

```html
<a href="#Index" class:active-link={currentPageName == 'Index'}>Index</a>
```

this will make sure the classes change as currentPageName changes.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring the function with the arrow syntax and making it reactive by adding `$:` it looks like alternatively to using the `class:directive` (which checks if value is truthy/falsy) the classname could be directly set inside the `class=""` attribute as well

A [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ed71dacd628146f1a68dda502a843f82?version=3.44.1)

```html
<script>
    let currentPageName = 'Index'

    $: isActive = (linkText) => {
        if (linkText === currentPageName) return 'active-link'
        // else if (...) return 'other-class-name' // possible class name switch
        else return ''
    }  
</script>

  <div class="">
    <a href="#Index" class="{isActive('Index')}">Index</a>   
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <a href="#Leaderboard" class="{isActive('Leaderboard')}">Leaderboard</a>   
  </div>

<br>
<button on:click={() => currentPageName = 'Leaderboard'}>change currentPageName</button>

<style>
    .active-link {
        color: purple;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately I got to initialize as many variables as I have of lines, and I need to repeat three times the name of the element name per line. But thanks for the answer !

Comment: Actually it might have been the right answer since we can access to the element thanks to the binding ! I'll accept the other one because it's the one I will use :)

Comment: @sidney sure :) I agree with the other answer, that it's the most straight solution and so probably the best... You don't need the element, so the binding is definitely unnecessary. I changed my answer to another approach of what you were trying to achieve which brings the before missing reactivity and might come in handy if different class names should be inserted